# Keypress event bubbling up from embedded browser

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I have a Firefox extension that adds a button to the toolbar (navbar to be exact). When the button is pressed, a XUL `<panel>` (which is a child element of the button) is opened with an `<iframe>` embedded in it. An HTML document is loaded into the panel to display the contents of the popup.

If the HTML contains an input field, I would not expect `keypress` events in that field to bubble up the DOM. However, they *do* bubble up to the `<panel>` that contains the embedded iframe and thereforth up to the toolbar button. Any idea why the panel gets the events even though they should be captured and processed by the HTML elements in the embedded browser?

Comment: You didn't happen to forget `type="content"`, did you? Note that input fields handle `keypress` events by merely calling `preventDefault()`, they don't stop event propagation.

Comment: Well the `type` of the iframe is `chrome` in this case, since we need the HTML document to have elevated privileges. Are you saying that the propagation behavior is different in this case?

Comment: Anyway, based on what you said, perhaps the behavior I am observing is normal and my solution (which is to catch and stop propagation of `keypress` events at the `<panel>` level) is correct.

Comment: Yes, `type="content"` is exactly what stops events from being propagated from the frame to the container document. Note that it has nothing to do with privileges, the document loaded into the frame can have elevated privileges regardless. Also: yes, stopping propagation of the events at a higher level is the usual solution.

Comment: Okay cool. If you had posted an answer I would have accepted it. :-P

Comment: Done. I simply expected your question to be a bit more tricky :)

Comment: Yeah, the only subtlety was that I didn't know that the normal behavior is due to crossing from content into chrome so it seemed weird to me that I was experiencing something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`type="content"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/iframe#a-browser.type) on your `<iframe>` tag for the events to stop at the frame boundary - that's one of the security mechanisms protecting browser's chrome from content pages. It also prevents JavaScript code in the frame from accessing the browser's chrome via `window.parent` and changing its location for example. Note that the frame can still have chrome privileges regardless of that - just like you can load a `chrome://` URL into a browser tab and it will work correctly.

The obvious alternative (for trusted frame content only) is to call [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/event.stopPropagation) in an event handler attached to the `<iframe>` tag. Note that default widgets (input fields included) don't do that when they handle events, they rather call [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault). This makes sure that higher-level widgets will normally ignore the event, your own code can still handle it however.

Comment: I ran into problems with `type="content"` even though I was loading a `chrome://` URL into the iframe (now I'm using my own protocol handler, but it gives the channel the system principal so it should be the same situation). I believe the problem was with cross-site XHR but I'd have to go back and do more testing to remember exactly. For now stopping propagation manually at the content/chrome boundary seems like a reasonable workaround.

Comment: Or maybe the problem was that the pages in the iframe can use XPCOM.